# Building the nginx rtmp module from source for Fedora: the module so file isn't built, and what about upgrades?

Tags: c, nginx, fedora, packaging

Sure, I've "chosen the wrong OS," Fedora instead of RHEL or CentOS, but I am where I am and there's no `rtmp` module in the standard distribution of nginx for Fedora since both RHEL and CentOS DO have the rtmp module available as a standard package.

So, I downloaded the source and did a build. While the call `make install` does the build (and I didn't see any errors in the 817 lines of output), it DOES NOT do the installation?!

At first I went down the wrong garden path, which is not totally wrong (see below as "Part II") but while writing "Part II" for this posting, I realized that I can't even find ANY evidence that it compiled ANY of the source for the rtmp module?! I followed the directions in the module's [github readme file.](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module#readme)

Of course, I kept a log of the run - too long to post here.

Having decades of coding experience I knew to check for a Makefile for that code and didn't find any?! STRANGE, right?

If anyone asks for info from that log, I have it and will provide it, but IDK what you may want to see from it.

Part II

I figured the installation didn't happen because the source code is written generically and doesn't pay any attention to the OS it's being installed on, and that's what "packaging" is all about and what package maintainers have to deal with...

I don't really have time to learn ALL the ins and outs of these packages, but I do know that the standard nginx packages provide these modules:

```
usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so
usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so
usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_mail_module.so
usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_naxsi_module.so
usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so
usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so
usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_vhost_traffic_status_module.so
```

However, I don't see the compilation creating ANY .so files, much less moving them where they go on Fedora (the default is apparently `/etc/nginx/modules`). Further, the log output directed me to look to /usr/local/nginx, and there no .o or .so files at all but rather a single binary. That's fine, but doesn't help me, I presume, unless I want to screw around with moving files from where they're "expected" from the OS vs nginx point's of view and that sounds to me like a time-sink of massive proportions.

However, this IS a one-off installation at the moment and I'd rather not have a lot of pain whenever this box (and likely others to follow if this works) needs an upgrade. So, I found this [gem of a blog posting.](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-installable-packages-dynamic-modules) It touches on this problem but also seems rather involved as I don't fully grock it yet.

**If I could simply learn how to build the correct file,** which I presume is intended to be (once installed):

```
/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_rtmp_module.so
```

...from the .c source files, then **I'm pretty sure I could "figure it out from there."**

(Another possibility might be to find a way to prove from some sort of analysis that the GetPageSpeed people didn't alter the source when providing [their package.](https://fedora.pkgs.org/35/getpagespeed-x86_64/nginx-module-rtmp-1.22.0+1.2.1-2.fc35.gps.x86_64.rpm.html) Or, perhaps I could convince the package maintainer to include the rtmp package in with the standard packages available for Fedora, but, well, at best that's a long  wait.)

Comment: tldr; what would be helpful is the makefile so we can tell what `make install` does.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the build from source skips the `.o` and `.so` file stages and just builds an executable.

It's not set up for running in the normal, modern Fedora environment, however, as already noted above.

Not finding another answer and wanting to move on to other things, I simply got this from-source version working and it wasn't that hard. Note that this presumes you've installed the standard `nginx` package(s), which in this case hook in your man pages, `systemd` interfaces and so on so you can manage it as usual. In your favorite shell, as root:

```
# First, for my own sanity:
#
cd /etc
mv nginx nginx.from_FC_distro
ln -s /usr/local/nginx
cd /usr/local/nginx/logs
mv error.log error.log.orig
ln -s /var/log/nginx/error.log
#
# Now, get it to run and STAY running:
#
cd /usr/sbin
mv nginx nginx.from_FC_Distro
# Then EITHER this:
cp -p /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx /usr/sbin/nginx.from_src
ln -s nginx.from_src nginx
# OR this:
ln -s /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
# Either vi or the echo works:
# vi /etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
echo "pid   /run/nginx.pid;" >> /etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
#
# Finally:
systemctl enable nginx.service
systemctl start nginx.service
```

And now you have a running installation of the `nginx` server with whatever config you set up in the config file WITH the `rtmp` service! AND, you can manage it as usual. Upgrades aren't so hard, either, just don't bother with upgrading the `nginx` package the usual way. I'm sure the script-kiddies can figure out how to script it based on [this article.](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-installable-packages-dynamic-modules)